# How do you embed an ipython console with exec_lines?

Tags: ipython, python-traitlets

I'm trying to embed an ipython console into my command line application.
I have the following:

```
import IPython
from traitlets.config import Config
c = Config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt',
    '%matplotlib',
]
return IPython.start_ipython(config=c, user_ns=globals())
```

However, it seems to completely ignore the "exec_lines" part since `plt` is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Can you specify a command to run after you embed into IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911570/can-you-specify-a-command-to-run-after-you-embed-into-ipython)

```
IPython.start_ipython(config=c, user_ns=locals())
```